# Nestjs project cannot find module google-play-scrapper

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-play, nestjs

I want to use this `https://github.com/facundoolano/app-store-scraper`, using NestJS project. Created the project using Nest new . already run`yarn install` and run the project using `npm run start:dev`.

Here is the error in my terminal:

```
    [Nest] 18464  - 01/12/2021, 4:14:13 pm   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot find module 'google-play-scrapper'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\app-scrapper\dist\app.service.js
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\app-scrapper\dist\app.controller.js
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\app-scrapper\dist\app.module.js
- C:\Users\USER\Desktop\app-scrapper\dist\main.js
Error: Cannot find module 'google-play-scrapper'
```

I just followed sample code:

app.service.ts code

```
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  getHello(): string {
    var gplay = require('google-play-scrapper');
    gplay
      .app({ appId: 'com.google.android.apps.translate' })
      .then(console.log, console.log);

    return 'Hello World!';
  }
}
```

What Am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

do `yarn add google-play-scraper` and replace that
`google-play-scrapper` with
`google-play-scraper`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-play-scraper